# Storing Country, State, City SQL Design

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, normalization

Is this how user location should be stored in a database? Is the   `user_Country_state_city` table necessary? Does anyone have a better design then whats listed below?

`User` table:

```
ID | User
0  | John
```

`user_Country_state_city`:

```
ID | CountryID | StateID | CityID
0  | 0         | 0       | 0
```

`Country`:

```
ID | Country Name
0  | United States
```

`State`:

```
ID | Country ID | State
0  | 0          | Michigan
```

`City`:

```
ID | State ID | City
0  | 0        | Detroit
```

OR

`User` table:

```
ID | User  | CountryID | StateID | CityID
0  | John  | 0         | 0       | 0
```

`Country`:

```
ID | Country Name
0  | United States
```

`State`:

```
ID | Country ID | State
0  | 0          | Michigan
```

`City`:

```
ID | State ID | City
0  | 0        | Detroit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are better approaches.  One is to have a `LocationId` in `Users`.  This, in turn, would reference a `Locations` table that has three columns, one for `City`, `State`, and `Country` -- or, better yet, `CityId`, `StateId`, and `CountryId`.

Another is to just have a `CityId` in the `Users` table.  This, in turn, would reference `States`, which in turn would reference `Country`.  In usual practice, cities are in a single state and states are in a single country.  You do not want to make it easy to violate this constraint, and this structure prevents that from happening.

Comment: So example 2 I created with just the cityID, and the city Table would have a reference to the country and state. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LeslieJones - In your second example you still have three references from `User`: `CountryId`, `StateId` and `CityId`. I believe Gordon is suggesting having only the `CityId` in `User`. Think about what it means. Can a user choose to be affiliated with only a country or must the specify a state and city? If so, why would you want to allow a user row to refer to Italy, Manitoba, Moscow? If you only allow a city and use it to locate the state, then country, you have precluded that problem.

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but I currently have the same problem and afaik a there are countries without states. My approach would be to have static tables with cities, states and countries, but cities refers to states and countries as well.

Comment: @F_Schmidt . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My rule for designing sql table is: if the relation is 1 to 1 (1 user has 1 location) then make it inside 1 table. It removes unnecessary overhead later for inner joining table.

So this come back to your business rules. Do you need 1 user have multiple location, or 1 user to have many location? If the former, then use 2nd approach (to set the value at user), else use 1st approach so it can do one-to-many relation.

Comment: 1 User 1 Location, so it would be a 1 to 1 relationship. The reason i dont want to put the country, state and city in the same table is it would be un-normalized. I was thinking 1 user  table , 1 country table 1 State Table and 1 city table maybe.

Comment: Why is put the country, state and city is un-normalized?